# jquery uploadify and oncomplete

Tags: jquery, uploadify

I am using uploadify in my cms.. basically, it opens in a popup window you upload.. that part all works.. however when i try to run a function in the parent window to refresh a panel to show new images it just freezes...

```
 onComplete: function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
          {
                window.opener.document.refreshFM(); 
    }
```

this is the onComplete function..

any ideas?

Comment: What freezes exactly? Any error messages? Does the event get executed?

Comment: Can we see the refreshFM function?

Comment: are you sure oncomplete get's executed.  also curious about what exactly you mean by "freeze"

Comment: Yeah if i put an alert box it fires.. wheni say freeze, the little percentage uploaded div just freezes at 100% and doestn dissapear...

<code>




function refreshFM(cls){
url = $("a."+cls).attr("href");
 path="";
 if ($("#"+id+"_path").val()!=undefined){path="&path="+$("#"+id+"_path").val();}else{path=""}
  url=url+""+path+"&FOLDER_NAME="+nf;
  exeAjax(url,cls,"openFM('"+cls+"')");
 }
}
</code>

Answer (score 0):

The controller action that handles the upload must return a value,try returning string "Ok" , paste the code from your controller action so we can help.